# Rubygems installation issue

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to install rubygems, to use with butler (IRC Bot)

Ruby installed sucessfully, using yum install ruby

and ruby -v give me `ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [i386-linux]`

Now, installing ruby gems, i am using `wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/76728/rubygems-1.8.25.zip` then `unzip rubygems-1.8.25.zip` everything unzips fine

Now, further in my [tutorial i am using](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3) it is telling me to do `ruby setup.rb` which i am doing and then, i am getting this error:

```
./lib/rubygems.rb:335: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
./lib/rubygems.rb:517: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
./lib/rubygems.rb:32:in `require': ./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:54: syntax error (SyntaxError)
        define_method name do |*args, &block| # TODO: really works on 1.8.7?
                                     ^
./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:55: syntax error
./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:64: syntax error
./lib/rubygems/deprecate.rb:69: syntax error    from ./lib/rubygems.rb:32
        from setup.rb:27:in `require'
        from setup.rb:27
```

I dont have a clue where to start to try and fix this, or what i need to do. I am looking to get rubygems installed, am i even doing it correct?

Comment: This is a common issue. Try to use RVM--- https://rvm.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the version of rubygems is compatible with your installed ruby version.

For Ruby 1.8.5, the latest compatible rubygems version is rubygems-1.3.5

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [i386-linux]
```

Here's how to install the version you need:

```
$ cd ~/sources
$ wget http://rubyforge.org/frs/download.php/60718/rubygems-1.3.5.tgz
$ tar xzvf rubygems-1.3.5.tgz
$ cd rubygems-1.3.5
$ sudo ruby setup.rb
RubyGems 1.3.5 installed

=== 1.3.5 / 2009-07-21

Bug fixes:

* Fix use of prerelease gems.
* Gem.bin_path no longer escapes path with spaces. Bug #25935 and #26458.

Deprecation Notices:

* Bulk index update is no longer supported (the code currently remains, but not
  the tests)
* Gem::manage_gems was removed in 1.3.3.
* Time::today was removed in 1.3.3.


------------------------------------------------------------------------------

RubyGems installed the following executables:
    /usr/bin/gem
```

It'm sure you've figured it out by now, but perhaps someone else that has to install rubygems on an older OS in the future can benefit from this info.

Here's the URL to find rubygems source download files:  http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126&release_id=15425